# Who are the Spider-Man incarnations shown in this Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse movie poster?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, spider-man, spider-man-across-the-spider-verse

Who* are the Spider-Man incarnations shown in this *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse* (2023) movie poster? The poster features some of the Spider-Man variations from the previous installment, *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse* (2018), but there are also a lot of new characters featured that I'm not familiar with.

<sup>* Those whose images are large and clear enough to be identified</sup>

[image: Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse movie poster]

<sup>Due to Imgur restrictions on image file size and resolution, I've cropped and then split the original image into two parts here so you can see a higher-resolution version of the characters. To view the full-sized images, click on the thumbnails below.</sup>

[image: left side of original image] [image: right side of original image]

<sup>Source and original, higher-resolution (4096 × 3099) version of the image: [@SpiderVerse, *Spider-Man: Across The Spider-Verse* official Twitter account 2023-01-20 tweet](https://twitter.com/SpiderVerse/status/1616133514025369632)</sup>

Comment: We need someone with The Skills to edit this with a picture with the various spider people numbered.

Comment: To start, the guy 2 to the left of Miles, with the all red suit and blue sleeveless hoodie over it I recognise as the Scarlet Spider/Ben Riley from comics in the 1990s.

Comment: I'm disappointed the human spider is conspicuously missing among the crowd.

Answer (score 17):

#### Right side of the poster

From right to left, front row to back row.

[image]
Spider-Man from [*The Spectacular Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_(TV_series)) (2008 animated TV series; Earth-26496)
<sub>- [Confirmed by  Christopher Miller](https://twitter.com/chrizmillr/status/1605230679838445568), one of the writers and producers of *Spider-Man: Across the Spider-Verse*</sub>

[image]
[Pavitr Prabhakar / Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(Pavitr_Prabhakar)) (2004 Spider-Man: India #1; Earth-50101)
<sub>This look and costume were shown in a [YouTube  video by Sony Pictures Entertainment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMr7JRtoYik)</sub>

[image]
["Werewolf Spider-Man"](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-7085)) (2007 Marvel Zombies/Army of Darkness Vol. 1 #5; Earth-7085)

[image]
["Last Stand" Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-312500)) (2003 Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 2 #58; Earth-312500)

[image]
[Gwen Stacy / Spider-Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Gwen_Stacy)) (returning from *Into the Spider-Verse* (2018); 2014 Edge of Spider-Verse Vol. 1 #2; Earth-65)

[image]
[Tarantula](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tarantula_(Earth-1610)) (2006 Ultimate Spider-Man Clone Saga; Ultimate Marvel universe / Earth-1610)

[image]
[Maybelle Reilly / Lady Spider](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maybelle_Reilly_(Earth-803)) (2014 Spider-Verse Vol. 1 #1; Earth-803)

[image]
Spider-Man from *[Spider-Man: Unlimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_Unlimited)* (1999 animated TV series; Earth-751263)

[image]
[Peter B. Parker / Spider-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-TRN701)) (returning from *Into the Spider-Verse* (2018))
<sup>In the trailer for *Across the Spider-Verse*, he was also wearing a pink bathrobe like in the poster:</sup>
[image: Peter B. Parker wearing a pink bathrobe]

[image]
[Spidercide](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spidercide_(Earth-616)) (1995 Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #399; part of the [1994 Clone Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_Saga) storyline; Earth-616)

[image]
[Hobie Brown / Spider-Punk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Punk) (2014 Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 3 #10; Earth-138)

[image]
[Margo Kess / Spider-Byte](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Byte_(Margo)_(Earth-22191)) (2018 Vault of Spiders Vol. 1 #1; Earth-22191)

[image]
[Eugene "Flash" Thompson / Captain Spider](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eugene_Thompson_(Earth-78127)) (1977 What If? Vol. 1 #7; Earth-78127)

[image]
[Spider-Man wearing Spider-Armor MK I](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_I) (1993 Web of Spider-Man Vol. 1 #100; Earth-616)

[image]
[Malala Windsor / Spider-UK](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Malala_Windsor_(Earth-835)) (introduced in the film)

[image]
Cyborg Spider-Woman (introduced in the film)
<sub>Source: [Official action figure merchandise for the film (shop.hasbro.com page of the action figure existed before the film was released)](https://shop.hasbro.com/en-us/product/marvel-spider-man-across-the-spider-verse-cyborg-spider-woman-toy-6-inch-scale-deluxe-action-figure-for-kids-ages-4-and-up/14EA4A37-5A53-48A3-A1C1-898F57E2CD49)</sub>

[image]
[Spider-Man wearing Spider-Armor MK II](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_II) (2011 Amazing Spider-Man Vol 1 #656; Earth-616)

[image]
[Charlotte Webber / Sun-Spider](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Charlotte_Webber_(Earth-20023)) (2019 Spider-Verse Vol. 3 #3; Earth-20023)

---

#### Left side of the poster

[image]
[Miguel O'Hara / Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099) (1992 Spider-Man 2099 Vol. 1 #1; Earth-928)

[image]
[Mary Jane Watson-Parker / Spinneret](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mary_Jane_Watson_(Earth-18119)) (2015 Amazing Spider-Man: Renew Your Vows Vol. 1 #1; Earth-18119)

[image]
Spider-Man from [*Marvel's Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2018_video_game)) (2018 video game developed by Insomniac Games; Earth-1048)

[image]
[Ben Reilly / Scarlet Spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Reilly) (1994 Spider-Man Vol. 1 #52; part of the [1994 Clone Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_Saga) storyline; the version that appeared in the film is the [Earth-94](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-94) version "In this reality, Ben Reilly didn't die at the hands of the Green Goblin, and kept being Spider-Man […]")

[image]
[Sir Peter Parker / Prince of Arachne](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-71004)) (2007 Spider-Man: Fairy Tales Vol. 1 #4; Earth-71004)

[image]
[Jessica Drew / Spider-Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Woman_(Jessica_Drew))  (1976 Marvel Spotlight Vol. 1 #32; Earth-616)
<sub>This look and costume were shown in a [YouTube video by Sony Pictures Entertainment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMr7JRtoYik)</sub>

[image: Doppelganger]
[Doppelganger](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doppelganger_(Spider-Man)_(Earth-616)) (1992 Infinity War #1; Earth-616)

[image]
["Ends of the Earth" Spider-Man, wearing Spider-Armor MK III](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Armor_MK_III) (2012 Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #682 "[Ends of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ends_of_the_Earth_(Marvel_Comics))" storyline; Earth-616)

[image]
["Bombastic Bag-Man"](https://spiderman.fandom.com/wiki/Spare_Fantastic_Four_Costume) / Spider-Man wearing a paper bag as a mask ([1984 Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #258](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_258); Earth-616)

[image]
[Julia Carpenter / Spider-Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_Carpenter) (1984 Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars Vol 1 #6; Earth-616)

[image]
[Patrick O'Hara / Web-Slinger](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Patrick_O%27Hara_(Earth-31913)) (2014 Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 3 #9; Earth-31913)

[image]
[Spider-Cat](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Cat_(Earth-999)) (2011 Spider-Island: I Love New York City Vol. 1 #1; Earth-999)

Answer (score 1):

Until someone does the hardwork of identifying all the spider men here's a list of all spider men confirmed to appear in Across the spider verse who are in the poster:

**19 Spider-Man (Miles Morales)**

**18 Spider-Gwen**

**17 Spider-Man 2099**

**16 Spider-Man (Peter B. Parker)**

**15 Spider-Woman**

**14 Spider-Punk**

**13 Japanese Spider-Man**

**12 Insomniac's Spider-Man**

.
**11 Spider-Man India**

**10 Scarlet Spider**

.
**9 The Superior Spider-Man**

**8 The Spectacular Spider-Man**

.
**7 Spider-Monkey**

.
**6 Bombastic Bag-Man**

**5 Lady Spider**

**4 Spider-Man (Marvel Mangaverse)**

**3 Spider-Man Unlimited**

**2 Madame Web (Julia Carpenter)**

**1 Spider-Girl**

And BTW it is quite [impossible](https://screenrant.com/spiderman-across-spiderverse-movie-sony-universes-characters-details/) to identify all spider men

[Source](https://movieweb.com/spider-man-across-the-spiderverse-confirmed-characters/#spider-girl)

Comment: This doesn't identify who's who though. Know where "16.) Spider-Man (Peter B. Parker)", "13.) Japanese Spider-Man", "9.) The Superior Spider-Man", "7.) Spider-Monkey", "4.) Spider-Man (Marvel Mangaverse)" and "1.)  Spider-Girl" are in the poster?